# How to use vectorization with if conditional logic

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements, vectorization

### Question

I am new to programming and am experiencing an issue with conditional logic. In my function the condition has length > 1 and thus only the first case of it being true will populate. How would I go about implementing the correct functionality?

### Output

I get incorrect information for the BaseQoQ and StressQoQ calculations for all regions with counter = 1. How would I modify my code so the correct information populates for a conditional with length > 1? I am new to R so any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of detailing on your code, I think it will be better if you post your sample of input data and expected output. Please explain the pictures.

Comment: Use of scoping assignment `<<-` indicates suboptimal design. And where is function called? And what is passed into it? Please backup and give us the whole *story* of your task here (i.e., what is the data and what are you trying to do). Else this reads as an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

The vectorised form of `if`condition in R is `ifelse`, whose definition can be found [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/ifelse). In your example one can have

```
with(HPF, 
    ifelse(index != 0, 
          case1, 
          case2)
)
```

notice that you may want to wrap `case1` (respectively `case2`) assignments into independent functions, to avoid confusions with the `ifelse` commas themselves.

Comment: I want to populate the same vector, stress_index based on the condition. How would I achieve this? It seems like the two conditions will create two vectors, I am only looking to create one. Change BaseC by delta for all elements <= term, otherwise keep BaseC unchanged and place into stress_index vector.

Comment: I don't understand your question: in the above code fill `case1` with the assignment should the condition be satisfied, `case2` otherwise: why would this create two different columns instead?

Comment: It's really hard to work with your code without you giving us a minimal reproducible example. Try to amend your question and provide us with a partial set of data that we can use to reproduce everything, otherwise answers are futile.